# All over codegolf, comments have an additional –

Tags: bug, status-norepro, meta

As seen in the image [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12461/basic-calculator-with-gui?noredirect=1#comment24368_12461) or anywhere else in codegolf:

[image]

The extra part is apparently :  `"–&nbsp;"`

I believe it's a bug?

Comment: I suspect you have changed the default character set for loading codegolf in your browser. Reset it to the default (or UTF-8) and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Oded. Whoever be the reason, I don't find the issue anymore as well. I had filed a bug at chrome though...

Answer (score 2):

The character `–` is U+2013, "en dash". It seems to be a display problem for your browser, not of the site in general.

Another way to write it is `&ndash;`, and it should appear in your browser as `–` (or – in roman text). Does that appear correctly for you?

Comment: Nope. it's same. Interestingly, when I edit in debug mode it renders correctly but not in browser.

Comment: Does it work for you if you use a different browser? I'm trying to see if the problem is with your browser or with your computer's locale settings, in general.

Comment: Yup, problem exists in one browser only. Works well in all others...

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce it anywhere else than codegolf in the same browser

Comment: But they haven't used `&ndash;`, so it's likely the browser is just using the wrong unicode encoding for some reason.

Comment: @gnibbler, when I view source in Chrome or Firefox I see `&ndash;&nbsp;`. Maybe they serve slightly different HTML to different browsers.